# MAC terminal code to change each letter of a text file to other letter

Tags: macos, encryption, terminal

(btw this is in macintosh OS X)
I didnt know what to really make my title, but the thing i want is, i want to write down some codes in terminal, and choose a .txt file, then the code will change each letter to something else, and other code to return it

for example:

i have .txt file as

Hello
123

after i write code in terminal it will be

x1yyc
ize

then i will write other code to reconvert it back to normal state

hello
123

please some help, i want it to be terminal codes nothing else i know there is software that do it but i need it in terminal pls help i apperiate u ! so much <3

Comment: how i would approach this problem is if i had a .txt file named (hello.txt) and it contained Hell0 123. I would have another .txt file named replace.txt with x1yyc ize. and then just cat replace.txt > hello.txt and it would override it

Comment: @KRUKUSA I think he wants to replace all characters with different characters based on a dictionary. Your solution supports "Hello 123" only. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tr` command to perform character substitution:

```
tr Helo123 x1ycize < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: ok, but i want to just for example type 
tr input.txt encrypt output.txt
and then
tr output.txt decrypt input.txt
i want this kind of codes, i know its not encrypt, its something to increase each letters char or something then decrease :( pls help

Comment: That's not how `tr` works, can't you read the man page? The arguments are a list of input characters and output characters, and it translates all the corresponding characters.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to have a pattern like increasing everything by the same amount. If they're random replacements, you need to list them all explicitly.